# Capybara integration test and fill_in for text fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am writing integration test for following html structure but i am stuck on text fields and capybara fill_in method

```
<div class="row" id="attr_3">
  <div class="span4">
    <input  name="description[]" type="text" value="Air Conditioning" />
  </div>
  <div class="span4">
    <input id="value_" name="value[]" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="attr_20">
 <div class="span4">
    <input  id="description_" name="description[]" type="text" value="Autopilot" />
 </div>
 <div class="span4">
    <input id="value_" name="value[]" type="text" value="" />
 </div>
</div>
```

This is a chunk of code Now I have to fill the value of text box whose description is "Air Condition". How I can do that? because there is no formal structure of this html and Air Condition is not label it is also a text box.

Comment: If you submit that form to a controller... what comes through in the `params` for the field you need to fill in? That is generally the name you can use for capybara.

Comment: These are nested attributes and every name in params received with the name of some "attr_3" _value and _description so i cant figured is out that which descriptions belongs to which value